# Navigation controller is drawing image leaving some points of opaque space on right, left and above side of custom image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am giving navigation bar custom background image of size 320x44 @1x, as so on 640x88 @2x ... but image is getting set as in screen shot leaving some space to right, left and above

Comment: Set AspectFill in storyBoard to image.

Comment: I m doing it programmatically. I have also tried AspectFill but it did'nt worked

Comment: What is your UIImage Frame. UIImage Frame must be (x ,y ,320 ,44) like this.

Comment: Can you post your code?